# Basic routing with two properties

Tags: url-routing, canjs

I make this routing test with properties, search and registration for vehicles

my code

```
$(function() {

  Router = can.Control({

      "vehicles" : function(){
        console.log("the hash is #!vehicles")
      },
      "vehicles/:registration" : function(data){
        console.log("the hash is #!vehicles/:registration "+data)
      },
      "vehicles/:search" : function(data){
        console.log("the hash is #!vehicles/:search "+data)
      }

    });


    can.route("vehicles");
    can.route("vehicles/:registration");
    can.route("vehicles/:search");

    can.route.ready();

    new Router(document);

});
```

and the tests

Test one

> > can.route.attr("search", "121-TYU-898")

```
a {_data: Object, _cid: ".map1", _computedBindings: Object, __bindEvents: Object, _bindings: 2…}
__bindEvents: Object
_bindings: 2
_cid: ".map1"
_computedBindings: Object
_data: Object
route: "vehicles/:search"
search: "121-TYU-898"
__proto__: t.Construct
```

That ok, but no message ("the hash is #!vehicles/:search "+data) in console

Test two

> > can.route.attr("registration", "333-TYU-898")

```
a {_data: Object, _cid: ".map1", _computedBindings: Object, __bindEvents: Object, _bindings: 2…}
__bindEvents: Object
_bindings: 2
_cid: ".map1"
_computedBindings: Object
_data: Object
registration: "121-TYU-898"
route: "vehicles/:registration"
__proto__: t.Construct
```

That ok, but no message ("the hash is #!vehicles/:registration "+data) in console

Test three

> > can.route.attr("search", "444-TYU-555")

```
a {_data: Object, _cid: ".map1", _computedBindings: Object, __bindEvents: Object, _bindings: 2…}
__bindEvents: Object
_bindings: 2
_cid: ".map1"
_computedBindings: Object
_data: Object
registration: "121-TYU-898"
route: "vehicles/:registration"
search: "333-TYU-808"
__proto__: t.Construct
```

I don't understand, for me, i expect this answer

```
a {_data: Object, _cid: ".map1", _computedBindings: Object, __bindEvents: Object, _bindings: 2…}
__bindEvents: Object
_bindings: 2
_cid: ".map1"
_computedBindings: Object
_data: Object
route: "vehicles/:search"
search: "444-TYU-555"
__proto__: t.Construct
```

Could you help to understand, thank you

Thank a lot Daff and i can make this ?

listen when property page is a particular value ?

example

```
$(function() {

  Router = can.Control({

      "route": function(){
        console.log("the hash is empty")
      },
      '{can.route} page=search': function(data){
              console.log("the hash is "+data.page+" with id "+data.id )

      },{can.route} page=registration': function(data){
              console.log("the hash is "+data.page)
      }

    });

    can.route(':page/:id');
    can.route.ready();

    new Router(window);

});
```

and

> > can.route.attr({page: "search", id: "123-jlkj-1231"})

and display in console

> > the hash is search with id 123-jlkj-1231

I tested, but this doesn't work :)

Do you see what I want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the CanJS route placeholders like variable names in JavaScript. Something like

```
function first(param1) {
}
```

and

```
function first(param2) {
}
```

Are the same as is `vehicles/:registration` and `vehicles/:type` matching the same route. What you probably want to do is this:

```
var Router = can.Control({
  "vehicles route" : function(){
    console.log("the hash is #!vehicles")
  },
  "vehicles/:type route" : function(data){
    console.log(data.type);
  }
});

new Router(document);
can.route.ready();
```

As shown in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4M58j/

You can also match routes like `"vehicles/search"` and `"vehicles/registration route"` (notice the missing `:` which is used as a variable palceholder.

Comment: Thank Daff, i added another answer, could you help me ?

"listen when property page is a particular value ?"

Comment: That would almost be a new question ;) Anyway, for this to work you need to include the can.Map.delegate plugin: http://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.delegate.html